# Restructure an array that has same object property values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have an array with objects that looks like this:

```
const array = [{label: "Color", content: "red"},{label: "Color", content: "blue"},{label: "Brand", content: "HI6"},{label: "Brand", content: "Zina"},{label: "Year", content: "2020"}];
```

I want to restructure it to look like this:

```
const array = [{label: "Color", content: ["red","blue"]},{label: "Brand", content: ["HI6", "Zina"]},{label: "Year", content: "2020"}];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen a lot of these questions here on SO, with answers. Surely there is at least one that will help you in your case. If not, please make an attempt. Then if your code still doesn't work, include your attempt and we'll be glad to help you out.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier please give me link or example. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const array = [{label: "Color", content: "red"},{label: "Color", content: "blue"},{label: "Brand", content: "HI6"},{label: "Brand", content: "Zina"},{label: "Year", content: "2020"}];

const mergeProperties = array => {
  const output = [];
  array.forEach( item => {
    if(!item.hasOwnProperty('label') || !item.hasOwnProperty('content')){
        return;
    }
    const alreadyExisting = output.find( outputItem => outputItem.label === item.label );
    if(alreadyExisting){
        alreadyExisting.content.push(item.content);
    }else{
        output.push({
           label: item.label,
           content: [item.content]
        })
    }
  })
  return output;
}

console.log(mergeProperties(array));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fg1qjc03/

The basic strategy is to keep track of an output array, which will be the result. As you go through each item, you check to see if that item's label has already been added to the output. If so, you just add the current item's content. If it hasn't (it's the first time), you add a whole new entry to the output (including the current item's content).

Comment: A lot of overhead in this approach.

Comment: Yep. It's written for clarity, not efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to add the item if it hasn't already been added or edit it if it already exists.

i.e.

```js
const array = [{
  label: "Color",
  content: "red"
}, {
  label: "Color",
  content: "blue"
}, {
  label: "Brand",
  content: "HI6"
}, {
  label: "Brand",
  content: "Zina"
}, {
  label: "Year",
  content: "2020"
}];

console.log(Object.values(array.reduce(function(result, item) {
  if (item.label in result) result[item.label].content.push(item.content);
  else result[item.label] = {
    label: item.label,
    content: [item.content]
  };
  return result;
}, {})));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `reduce` along with the function `Object.values` as follow:

Basically, the function `reduce` groups the objects by `label` and the function `Object.values` retrieves the grouped objects as an array.

```js
const array = [{label: "Color", content: "red"},{label: "Color", content: "blue"},{label: "Brand", content: "HI6"},{label: "Brand", content: "Zina"},{label: "Year", content: "2020"}],
      result = Object.values(array.reduce((r, {label, content}) => {
        (r[label] || (r[label] = {label, content: []})).content.push(content);
        return r;
      }, {}));

console.log(result);
```